# How can I remove the dropdown option in country in checkout page in magento? I need to put only one country

Tags: php, magento, drop-down-menu, country, onepage-checkout

I did this trick converting php line

```
<?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
```

to html line but not worked. In site showing one blank line and other line India. I need only one line India or remove dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

If it's loading the default country, India, correctly, and you want to possibly use other country codes in the future, you can just disable the field with CSS so that the option can't be changed by the user:

```
.input-country {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow following step.

Step 1:-First of all login in your magento admin

Step2:-Now go System->Configuration->general->Countries Options->Allow Countries and select one country you want to display.

Step 3:-save config.

Step 4:-Now clear Cache.

Step 5:-then you see one country on checkout page.